# 'Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly' when running 2013 sp1 DB upgrade scripts

Tags: 2013, upgrade, database, 2013-sp1

I'm running the SDL Tridion 2013 Sp1 database upgrade scripts but running into the following error :

```
Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Tridion 2013
SP1\database\Scripts\Tridion.Database.Management.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
At C:\U\Tridion 2013 SP1\database\Scripts\Utilities.ps1:16 char:1
+ Import-Module (Join-Path -Path $PSScriptDir -ChildPath "..\Scripts\Tridion.Datab 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand.
```

To run I'm navigating directly to the script directory and running:

```
& '.\Upgrade Content Manager database.ps1'
```

or

```
& '.\Upgrade Content Data Store.ps1'
```

My set up is 2013 GA, running on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Check out number 6 in the docs: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-F056D405-1C30-446C-8FBA-9B723B73D999

Comment: @AlbertRomkes - can you put this as answer, this is what helped me resolve the issue :)

Comment: If you downloaded the install package zip via Chrome or FIrefox it blocks everything in it. Unblock the zip before unpacking

Comment: run in version 3. I love you. made my day

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to unblock the `Tridion.Database.Management.dll` as described in the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-F056D405-1C30-446C-8FBA-9B723B73D999) (bullet 6, login required)

Answer (score 4):

Couple of things, I suspect for generating `'Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly'` error

1. Make sure you enable .Net 4.0 for powershell

Create a file **“powershell.exe.config”** in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.6" />    
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

2. DLL might be blocked, it needs to un-block

Answer (score 2):

If you have "IE Enhanced Security Configuration" (ON by default in Windows 2012 R2) then this also causes the problem you have if your install files are on a Network Drive.

You can just switch it off in Server Manager
or
Add the Network Drive Server into your Trusted sites

Add file://networkdriveservername into the Local Internet Sites in IE
Internet Explorer |Options | Security |Local Intranet | Sites

You can also do this with PowerShell

```
Function AddManagementServerToTrustedSites 
{
Param ([string]$TrusterServer)

$TrustedSitesPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\EscDomains'
$TrustedKeyPath = "$TrustedSitesPath\$TrusterServer"
$LocalIntranetZone = 1
$TrustedSitesZone = 2

If (!(Test-Path -Path $TrustedKeyPath))
{New-Item -Path $TrustedSitesPath  -Name $TrusterServer} #Add site if not present

$Item = Get-Item -Path $TrustedKeyPath
If ($Item.GetValue('file',$null) -eq $null)
{New-ItemProperty -Path $TrustedKeyPath -Name file -PropertyType DWord -Value $LocalIntranetZone} # Add file key if not present

$key = Get-ItemProperty $TrustedKeyPath -Name file 
if ($key.file -ne 1 )
{Set-ItemProperty $TrustedKeyPath -Name file -Value $LocalIntranetZone} # set file key to 1 if not 1

Write-Log "$TrusterServer is trusted in Local Intranet Zone"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason a different `PowerShell` version might be started. Make sure you are using at least version 3:

```
powershell.exe -v 3
```

And see the accepted answer to unblock the dll.